# Moment get the HH and ss

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am using moment.js. I have a variable that moment converts in to HH:ss format:

```
var mins, hours, time;

time = moment(selectedTime).format("HH:mm");
```

Which returns something like: 14:43 for example.

How can i get:

```
var hours to equal 14
var mins to equal 43
```

I have tried:

```
var mins, hours, time;

time = moment(selectedTime).format("HH:mm");

hours = moment(time).get('hour');
```

Which then hours returns NaN

Comment: Just use `moment(selectedTime).hour()`, no need to go through its string representation to get hour part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var hours = moment(selectedTime).hours();
var mins = moment(selectedTime).minutes();
```

see http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/minutes/

Answer (score 1):

The Solution that NimS has provided should work perfectly and suits your case very well. However if you simply need to display the values you can use the `moment().format(XXX)` method as you were previously and use the appropriate tokens from the [documentation](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/)

For example

```
var mins, hours, time;

time = moment(selectedTime).format("HH:mm");

hours = moment(time).format('HH');
mins = moment(time).format('mm');
```

Take a look at the above example and you can format the time in any way you choose

Comment: Thanks for the above. I am seeing Invalid Date, even if i hard code the value e.g. mins  = moment("10:43").format('mm').. mis will display Invalid Date.

Comment: If you specify a time/date in a non standard format you need to tell moment the format ie. `moment("10:43", 'HH:mm').format('mm')`.